# Rails + Google Calendar Event Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I would really like to import events from my google calendar into my rails application. Right now, I'm not sure what the best way of doing that would be. I know that I can probably pull down the ics/xml file from my private calendar link and then somehow parse that but I was wondering if there was an easier way to go about doing this.

For reference, I did try to use the gcal4ruby gem and it kept throwing me the error:
        no such file to load -- gcal4ruby

I installed the gem using: 
        sudo gem install gcal4ruby

I also tried to add it to my gemfile and then bundle install but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: What effect were you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [GCal4Ruby](https://github.com/SeabourneConsulting/GCal4Ruby) and [this demo app](https://github.com/juno/rails3-jquerymobile-gcal-example)